# Programmatically adding a TextView onto an existing XML file

Tags: java, android, xml

My main screen displays info from user input.

[image]

Now everything on this screen is added using XML apart from "Kool" TextView on the top left corner. Now I want a way to get info from a user and add it underneath the first row of information.

I've sorted out the screen that gets user input the problem is actually getting the layout perfect. Now I added "Kool" TextView programmatically but the layout is wrong.

How can I make it so it so the "Kool" TextView is underneath the date "20/08/15". Every time I use the setHeight method it makes the TextView invisible.

Code:

```
 public class AnalysisPage extends Activity {

Button savebutton,cancelbutton;
EditText dateinput,weightinput,repsinput;
int dd,mm,yy;

private TextView texty = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dumbbellpress);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions,menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){


    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.addinfo:
            Dialog dialog = new Dialog(AnalysisPage.this);
            dialog.setTitle("    Enter your STATS brah");
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.datainput);

            dateinput = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.editDate);
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            dd = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            mm = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            yy = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);

            dateinput.setText(new StringBuilder().append(dd).append("/").append(mm+1).append("/").append(yy));

            dialog.show();


            weightinput = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.editWeight);
            repsinput = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.editReps);

            savebutton = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
            cancelbutton = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);

            savebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {



                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    RelativeLayout views = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.xxx);

                    texty = new TextView(AnalysisPage.this);
                    texty.setTextSize(28);
                    texty.setText("Kool");



                    views.addView(texty);

                }
            });

            cancelbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

XML code:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" android:weightSum="1" android:id="@+id/statslayout">

<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/xxx">

    <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp" android:id="@+id/tableRow3" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" android:layout_marginStart="72dp">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Dumbbell Press Stats!"
                android:id="@+id/textView"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp" android:id="@+id/tableRow"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_marginTop="49dp" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tableRow3">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Date"
                android:layout_weight="0.22"
                android:id="@+id/btnDate"
               />
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="  Weight"
                android:layout_weight="0.22"
                android:id="@+id/txtWeight"
                />

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="  Reps"
                android:layout_weight="0.22"
                android:id="@+id/btnReps"
               />


    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tableRow" android:layout_alignParentStart="true" android:id="@+id/tableRow4">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="20/08/15"
                android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_below="@+id/tableRow"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tableRow3"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="  8"
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_marginEnd="82dp" android:layout_below="@+id/tableRow"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/tableRow3"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="50kg"
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_marginStart="43dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tableRow3" android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tableRow4"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My end (dream) goal for this is by using Java I making complete perfectly formatted rows which contains the Date, Weight and Reps in their respected columns. And multiple rows of this or perfectly formatted using Java.

Image (this is in XML not in Java)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Rather than add TextView(s) programmatically, use a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html). This will solve your problems entirely. You would use a custom adapter [setAdapter()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)) that your ListView would set as it's adapter (that provides the List it's data), and add new row elements each time you click your button that adds the new items. This would mean replacing your TableRow bit, and using a ListView in the RelativeLayout instead. Also, you could add a custom header view to the ListView to replace that header you already use (source: [addHeaderView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView(android.view.View)) )

Looking at your rows, it appears that they have the fields: "Date", "weight" and "reps". This would mean create a custom Java object that has those three fields, and make the the object type of your ListView adapter's elements. I can provide starter code if you REALLY need it, but it would help you best to use the documentation I provided to teach your self how to use the ListView.

Tutorial: [ListView tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)

Edit: **Another bonus**: ListView handles allowing the user to scroll as more, and more rows are added to this List of yours. More reason to just opt to a ListView :)

Comment: Okay thanks very much I have been looking through the documentation. Can you please just provide a little bit of starter code? Just so it displays the header section (Date,Weight,Reps).